# Powershell File Checking Loop

Tags: powershell

The below script does a file verification on given path. The script return if found any of the file is missing... I would like to complete the checking of all 4 files mentioned and then return if any of one missing.. How i need to change the code..

Also need to capture the logs in a  variable for mailing purpose.. 
Thanks in Advance..

```
$LocalPath = "D:\Data\Inst"
$paths = foreach($file in @("\abcd.exe", "\xyz.exe", "\IND\123.exe", "\ENG\987.exe"))
{
"$LocalPath$file"
}

foreach ($fullpath in $paths)
{
write-host "Varifying File : $fullpath"
If (-not (Test-Path $fullpath -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue") ) 
{ 
write-host "`nFile varification $fullpath Failed.!! `a`n "

return 
}
ELSE
{
write-host "$fullpath : is available `n"
}
}
```

Comment: Set a boolean flag instead of returning and then check the value of the flag at the end of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```powershell
$LocalPath = "D:\Data\Inst"
$paths = "\abcd.exe", "\xyz.exe", "\IND\123.exe", "\ENG\987.exe" | ForEach-Object{
    "$LocalPath$_"
}

$results = $paths | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Path = $_
        Exists = Test-Path $_ -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
    } 
}

if ($results.Exists -contains $False){
    $results | Where-Object{$_.Exists -eq $false} | ForEach-Object{ Write-Warning "$($_.Path) does not exists."}
    return
} Else {
    Write-Host "All paths are present."
}
```

Test each file and record the result of each Test-Path into a custom variable. Then we check if *any* of the results are `$False`. If one is then we show the one that does not exist and return.

Optionally, depending on your needs, you could output the variable `$results` to file now.

```
$results | Export-CSV C:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
# Files to check
$ToCheck = @{'D:\Data\Inst' = @('abcd.exe', 'xyz.exe', 'IND\123.exe', 'ENG\987.exe')}

# Check files
$Log = $ToCheck.GetEnumerator() |
            ForEach-Object {
                foreach ($File in $_.Value){

                    $CurrFile = Join-Path -Path $_.Key -ChildPath $File
                    "Verifying File : $CurrFile"
                    if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $CurrFile -PathType Leaf)
                    {
                        "$CurrFile : is available"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $FileMissing = $true
                        "File verification $CurrFile Failed.!!"
                    }
                }
            }

# Send email
if($FileMissing)
{
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' -From 'script@company.com' -To 'admin@company.com' -Subject 'File status' -Body $Log
}
```